# Welp! Where are my tags?

Tags: bug, tags

I've seen this since... mm... yesterday? Well, in the sidebar over the amount of views I'm supposed to see something like this:

[image]

But instead I see this:

[image: SO]

[image: AU]

This happens on Chromium Version 31.0.1650.63 Debian jessie/sid (238485).

`.module.question-stats` doesn't have `tagged` element

Comment: I saw a dupe somewhere. It's A/B testing.